# Как извлечь стили из Word на C++

Tags: c++, xml, парсер, ms-word

Пишу программу для автоматической проверки форматирования в Word. Стало ясно что для извлечения стилей нужно парсить XML. Выбор пал на [TinyXML](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/index.html). Отсюда вопрос – подойдет ли он для парсинга вордовского XML со стилями? Есть ли библиотеки, которые подойдут для этой задачи лучше?

Также если вы сталкивались с этой задачей, то есть ли у вас какие-нибудь наработки или полезные статьи?

Comment: Это жесткое требование - использовать C++, или Ваш выбор?

Comment: @isnullxbh да, к сожалению, это жесткое требование, иначе все было бы уже написано на Python c bs4

Comment: Форматы офисных документов очень сложны. Разбирать их вручную - сомнительное удовольствие. Поищите готовые библиотеки. В мире .NET широко известны OpenXml, ClosedXml. А в мире нативного C++ всё довольно печально: какие-то библиотеки есть, но или старые, или поддерживают не все возможности ms office.

Comment: C# я не знаю, да и писать можно только на C++/Delphi. Аналоги OpenXML или ClosedXML под C++ я не нашёл.